# An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Pessoal estou com um problema meio chato, estou tentando fazer um update usando o  *Entity Framework*, mas quando chega no SaveChanges(); aparece o seguinte erro.

**An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.**

Pelo que encontrei na internet tem algo relacionado com a instancia do meu context, tentei fazer uma nova instancia mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

Segue o código:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditPassword([Bind(Include = "intIDUsuario,strNome,strUsuario,strSenha,bitStatus,strTelefone,strEmail,intIDPerfil,NovaSenha,ConfirmaSenha")] Usuario usuario)
    {
        try
        {

            var query2 = from q in db.Usuario where q.intIDUsuario == usuario.intIDUsuario select q.intIDUsuario;
            int id1 = query2.FirstOrDefault();


            string pass = Cryptography.Encrypt(usuario.strSenha);

            var user = db.Usuario.ToList().Where(x => x.strSenha == pass && usuario.NovaSenha == usuario.ConfirmaSenha).Count() > 0;

            if (user)
            {

                usuario.strSenha = Cryptography.Encrypt(usuario.NovaSenha);

                db.Entry(usuario).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index","Suporte");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Suporte");

        }
        catch
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError("","Ocorreu um erro!!!");

        }

        return View(usuario);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Isto acontece porque você está selecionando o usuário várias vezes. Por padrão, o Entity Framework monitora todos os objetos carregados, mesmo que não haja alteração neles.

Para evitar que objetos somente leitura sejam monitorados, utilize o seguinte:

```
        var query2 = from q in db.Usuario where q.intIDUsuario == usuario.intIDUsuario;
        int id1 = query2.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault().Select(q => q.intIDUsuario);

        string pass = Cryptography.Encrypt(usuario.strSenha);

        var user = db.Usuario.AsNoTracking().Count(x => x.strSenha == pass && usuario.NovaSenha == usuario.ConfirmaSenha) > 0;
```

[`AsNoTracking`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) carrega os objetos "num modo somente leitura". Realizando estas alterações, seu código deve funcionar normalmente.

Comment: Na linha 
`var query2 = from q in db.Usuario where q.intIDUsuario == usuario.intIDUsuario select q.intIDUsuario;

 int id1 = query2.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();`
Aparece o seguinte erro
**The type 'int' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.AsNoTracking<T>(System.Linq.IQueryable<T>)'**

Comment: @DiegoDias Cara, esqueci de editar a resposta pra você no dia! Foi mal mesmo. Agora está ok.