# Attach de muitos objetos com id = 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Bom dia Pessoal,

No meu sistema aqui no trabalho eu tenho a seguinte arquitetura: Um PROJETO (que tem algumas informações) é composto por várias PARTES. As partes são bem diferentes entre si. Uma, por exemplo a parte 1, possui vários documentos anexos.

A view de Projetos foi montada com uma Tab Panel (uma aba para cada parte) de forma que o usuário pode alterar várias partes de uma só vez.

No controller de Projetos, eu recebo o modelo Projeto da view, com todas as suas alterações e inclusões. E começo a analisá-lo:

```
    private void salvar(Projetos projeto)
    {
        try
        {
            resolverParte1(projeto);
            resolverParte2(projeto);
            ...

            ctx.Entry(projeto).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
  }

  private void resolverParte1(Projetos projeto)
  {

        foreach(var d in projeto.Documentos.ToList())
        {
            // Documento alterado
            if(d.id != 0)
            {
                 ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else // Documento adicionado
            {
                 d.Parte1Id = parte1Id;
                 ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
         }

         ctx.Projetos.Attach(projeto);

         ICollection<Documentos> dLista = null;

         ctx.Entry(projeto).Collection("Documentos").Load();
         dLista = projeto.Documentos;

         // A lista de documentos que permaneceu no banco como Unchanged é porque foi excluída na view
         var apagados = (from d in dLista where ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Unchanged select d).ToList();

         foreach(var a in apagados)
         {
              ctx.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Deleted;
         }
    }
```

O problema que estou tendo é que ao adicionar dois ou mais documentos (d1 e d2), eles chegam ao controller com id = 0 (porque estou adicionando) e ao executar a linha do attach, ocorre a seguinte exception **"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key"**.

Por favor, alguém saberia como resolver isso?

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é muito parecido [com esta resposta que dei, em que o autor da pergunta tem o mesmo erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54262/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-the-object/54267#54267), mas não merece ser tratada como duplicada porque, para o seu caso, a resposta merece considerações adicionais.

Por exemplo, esta parte:

```
    foreach(var d in projeto.Documentos.ToList())
    {
        // Documento alterado
        if(d.id != 0)
        {
             ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else // Documento adicionado
        {
             d.Parte1Id = parte1Id;
             ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
     }

     ctx.Projetos.Attach(projeto);
```

Como `projeto.Documentos` implementa `ICollection`, `projeto.Documentos.ToList()` é desnecessário. O trecho pode ser reescrito como:

```
foreach(var d in projeto.Documentos) { ... }
```

Outra coisa é a respeito de entidades agregadas. A partir do Entity Framework 6, este bloco `foreach` é desnecessário, visto que o contexto já tenta resolver alterações, inclusive, nas entidades dependentes. Ou seja, o bloco todo pode ser substituído por:

```
ctx.Entry(projeto).State = EntityState.Modified;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Ainda, a declaração abaixo:

```
ctx.Projetos.Attach(projeto);
```

É incorreta neste ponto do código. [Segundo a própria documentação oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx), `Attach` deve ser usado quando você sabe duas coisas:

- O objeto ainda não foi carregado no contexto;
- O objeto existe no banco.

Não é o caso aqui. `projeto` já foi carregado antes. O correto é usar:

```
ctx.Entry(projeto).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Outro detalhe preocupante é aqui:

```
    // A lista de documentos que permaneceu no banco como Unchanged é porque foi excluída na view
     var apagados = (from d in dLista where ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Unchanged select d).ToList();

     foreach(var a in apagados)
     {
          ctx.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Deleted;
     }
```

Aqui você marca os registros originais como `EntityState.Deleted` mas só chama `ctx.SaveChanges()` na função pai, o que é, do ponto de vista transacional, não apenas incorreto como também uma má prática.

Para incluir um escopo transacional no seu código, use:

```
private void salvar(Projetos projeto)
{
    try
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) 
        {
            resolverParte1(projeto);
            resolverParte2(projeto);
            ...

            ctx.Entry(projeto).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            scope.Complete();
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Se você faz questão de manter a lógica para resolução de partes em separado, a lógica pode receber escopo transacional aninhado:

```
private void resolverParte1(Projetos projeto)
{
     using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) 
     {
         ctx.Entry(projeto).State = EntityState.Modified;
         ctx.SaveChanges();

         ICollection<Documentos> dLista = null;

         ctx.Entry(projeto).Collection("Documentos").Load();
         dLista = projeto.Documentos;

         // A lista de documentos que permaneceu no banco como Unchanged é porque foi excluída na view
         var apagados = (from d in dLista where ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Unchanged select d).ToList();

         foreach(var a in apagados)
         {
             ctx.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Deleted;
         }

         scope.Complete();
    }
}
```